# Access Javascript Array with numeric key

Tags: numeric

I tried to access the following value in an multidimensional array:

```
var temp = allSliderData[i]['slider_full'][j].path;
```

and it works fine, but the following not

```
var temp2 = allSliderData[i]['slider_thumbs'][j].285x255;
```

with the answer
**"SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal"**

I now tried escapings, array functions .. this message is good known in stackoverflow .. but still no luck.

Could anybody help out?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that won't work. You can't have a property named "2" there. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I have the need to access the value .. for temp it's fine.. for temp2 and the numeric key not..  this array comes from php into my my js .. there is no option to change the key name on php side.. only the attemp with js is give.

Comment: The problem is, that JavaScript doesn't allow naming propertys with a number as the first value. If it's a key, you need to do it like [j] ["285x255"]

Comment: YES - this escaping solution totally works - thanks @Bitte Wenden !

Comment: Great! I highly recommend the "You don't know JavaScript" books, if you want to avoid these mistakes in the future.